# Openssl for Android x86_64 and mips64

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, x86-64, android-5.0-lollipop

I have built openssl for 5/7 of the android-21 (android-L) architectures: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64, mips, x86. However I am unable to build it for x86_64 and mips64.

## What I'm doing...

#### x86 - working

The following is my working script for x86, using a toolchain created by make-standalone-toolchain:

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/Users/jacsteve/dev/android/ndk
export ANDROID_API=android-21
export ANDROID_ARCH=arch-x86
export ANDROID_EABI=i686-linux-android-4.9
export ANDROID_SYSROOT=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/$ANDROID_API/arch-x86
export ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=/tmp/toolchain/x86
export ANDROID_DEV=$ANDROID_SYSROOT/usr

export SYSTEM=android
export ARCH=x86

export CROSS_COMPILE=i686-linux-android-

export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export CXXFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"

./Configure android-x86 shared no-asm -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw --cross-compile-prefix=$CROSS_COMPILE --openssldir=/tmp/ssl/x86

make depend
make
make install
```

This works fine, and leaves me with `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so` in `/tmp/ssl/x86`

#### x86_64 - fails

However, x86_64 fails. Here's the script:

```
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/Users/jacsteve/dev/android/ndk
export ANDROID_API=android-21
export ANDROID_ARCH=arch-x86_64
export ANDROID_EABI=x86_64-linux-android-4.9
export ANDROID_SYSROOT=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/$ANDROID_API/arch-x86_64
export ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=/tmp/toolchain/x86_64
export ANDROID_DEV=$ANDROID_SYSROOT/usr

export SYSTEM=android
export ARCH=x86_64

export CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-linux-android-

export CFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export CXXFLAGS="--sysroot=$ANDROID_SYSROOT"

./Configure android-x86 shared no-asm -m64 -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw --cross-compile-prefix=$CROSS_COMPILE --openssldir=/tmp/ssl/x86_64

make depend
make
make install
```

## The Errors...

#### x86_64

I get a load of error messages from the `make` call that look like this:

```
/private/tmp/toolchain/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
error: libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o): incompatible target
/private/tmp/toolchain/x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld:
error: libcrypto.a(mem.o): incompatible target
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It looks to me like `x86_64-linux-android-gcc` is compiling everything fine, but when we get to the linking stage, `x86_64-linux-android-ld` can't read the compiled object files.

#### mips64

Using a similar setup for mips64 (with `./Configure android-mips ...`) I get the following error, which looks to be a similar issue to do with `mips64-linux-android-ld` being unable to read object files:

```
/Users/jacsteve/dev/android/ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-mips64/usr/lib/libdl.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Does anyone know how to build the x86_64 and mips64 architectures successfully?

Comment: Jack, I know this question is very old, but would it be possible to share the configuration you used for these builds? I'm trying to build arm64, mips64 and x86_64.

Comment: Sure! When I did this I whipped up a quick bash script - I've put it on github just for you :) https://gist.github.com/cogwirrel/4a733b4138d1b35d4cfe69b4df110d0b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

Instead of

```
./Configure android-x86 ...
```

I used

```
./Configure linux-generic64 ...
```

I also used `linux-generic32` for the 32bit architectures.

Answer (score 1):

Running `make clean` before ./Configure solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error from building openssl for mips64, I guess, resulted from the incompatible ABI format between objects and libraries, which the format objects is mips-ELF64, while libraries provided by ANDROID_NDK is mips ELF32

```
cd ${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}/platforms/android-24/arch-mips64/usr/lib
readelf -h libc.so
  ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           MIPS R3000
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xa7d0
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          204792 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x50001007, noreorder, pic, cpic, o32, mips32
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         18
  Section header string table index: 15
```